# Unable to call component within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting exception like

> "Invariant Violation: Expected onMountComponent() to fire for the
>   child before it's parent includes it in onSetChildren()"

Calling one component inside another like

```
const Forms = this.props.Forms.map(Form=> {
    return(
        <table className ="tableN table table-striped table-bordered" key = {Form.get('uid')}>
            <thead style={{fontSize:'9pt'}}>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Subject:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                      <label>Form details:</label>
                      <SomeForm Form={Form}/>
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
     )
 })
```

SomeForm is another component
What could be possible cause for this error???

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I wonder if you wrap the contents of the <td> in a div it'll behave. Shot in the dark though

Comment: Can you share your full component code?